# What is the technical name of this 0.635mm pin?

Tags: identification

I have several components that I'd like connect to a circuit on the breadboard, and have found that the pin highlighted is ideal for that.  I know it's a 0.635mm pin and searching online it seems to be referred to as a Molex pin, but that's a brand name, so my question is what is the technical name of this part?

[image: Pin]

Comment: Aren't these known as dupont connectors, so it would be a "male dupont connector"?

Comment: Thank you!  I have never heard that term until now (always heard "molex"), but that appears to be it.  Appreciate it @jakob

Comment: DuPont is just another brand - Mini PV is the name of that series, but that's just another name. Not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Arsenal, I'm looking for the term that I'd used to locate the part, analogous to searching for a resistor, capacitor, etc.

Comment: 'Berg pin' is another brand name. The size is '25 thou' (0.025") which may help?

Comment: The closest thing is probably the description of what it actually is: 0.635mm square pin. Or 0,100: square pin since it is almost always use with 0.100" pitch.

Comment: Note the pin is just the internal part of the connector, with the plastic housing removed.

Comment: I call them "2,54mm lab junk" :)

Answer (score 14):

Hobbyists call them "Dupont male pins"  or ".. jumper pins" and the nominal pin dimension is typically specified as 0.64mm. You can find them under those and similar names from sources such as Aliexpress, Banggood and Amazon. They're generally about the right shape and might work okay. Image below from Amazon.ca

[image]

If you want to stick them in a housing (and be retained) they should be matched up with the same manufacturer's housing.

If you want higher quality pins you can find similar products from Amp, Mill-max, Molex etc., and housings to match but the price per pin might be 10-20dB higher. Highest price would be screw machine gold plated parts. Lowest would be relatively good quality stamped parts.

Comment: I like the price difference in dB :)

Comment: But is price per pin a power quantity or a root-power quantity? 

Comment: @TannerSwett Money is power so \$10\cdot\log_{10}\$(price).

Answer (score 8):

Figuring out what connector parts you need can be pretty tricky, especially when "hobbyist" names, working names, and actual product names differ so dramatically. For example, hobbyists commonly call these "DuPont" connectors... and I have *no idea* where this came from, because I have *never* seen a connector made by DuPont. I would describe it as a male pin crimp contact for a 100-mil pitch rectangular pin header, but even that is not super useful to get towards something that you can order.

Digikey has an [outstanding article](https://forum.digikey.com/t/dupont-connectors-and-how-to-find-them-from-digi-key/3315?utm_adgroup=Connectors%20%26%20Interconnects&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_RLSA_Cart&utm_term=&utm_content=Connectors%20%26%20Interconnects&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgreUpvmx9wIV9GxvBB1J7wQDEAAYASAAEgJ6mPD_BwE) on how to use their catalog to find connectors in the style that you're looking for, especially if you're looking for multiple pin contacts. It looks like this is more useful for getting 2-24  pin connectors (both crimp pins and plastic housings) instead of single crimp pins and 1x1 housings.

Getting to an orderable part number, I would recommend finding the housing series that you're looking for from a manufacturer, and then identifying compatible parts through that manufacturer. As @Arsenal mentioned, Mini-PV is the Amphenol/FCI product line, and AMPMODU is the TE Connectivity product line. Match product numbers and brands to make sure the housing and contacts will work together.

One last tip for finding pins and contacts is to sort by stock, descending. These are super common parts, and it's common for distributors such as Digikey and Mouser to stock >10,000 contacts. That'll help filter out oddball parts that have a lot of similar search terms.

Comment: Berg invented these and then was passed around between 3M, DuPont, Amphenol, and Molex, I don't recall which order the take-overs and divestments happened.  DuPont did briefly produce connectors like these.

Comment: @jasen Fascinating - if my random research on the internet is correct, then DuPont owned the Mini-PV brand between 1972 and 1993... which also explains why I've never seen DuPont selling connectors. http://www.mattmillman.com/why-do-we-call-these-dupont-connectors/

Answer (score 0):

I've not only encountered "Dupont cables" (same here, no idea why), but also "jumper wires" or just simply "breadboarding/prototyping wires". The most common in my personal experience was "jumper wires". Those come either male-male, female-female, or male-female.